# Accessing Calendar, Mail and Contacts of an OAuthenticated user

Tags: oauth, exchangewebservices, azure-active-directory

I configured an application on AzureAd to be multi-tenant, I chose to require all the permissions for Windows Azure Active Directory and Office 365 Exchange Online.

I can get a user to grant permissions, get access tokens, refresh them, OAuth works for me. I always used the "common" keyword instead of the tenant ID, because my app is multi-tenant.

Now, I would like to have (CRUD) access to a user's Mail, Contacts and Calendar with this token. Here is my problem: I am completely lost in all the possible API endpoints. Should I use: graph.windows.net, outlook.office365.com, graph.microsoft.com? [This page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview) seems to suggest that graph.microsoft.com is the Swiss army knife that would serve my purpose, but somehow I cannot find a doc that allows me to find the info I'm looking for. Plus, it seems under development and maybe too incomplete for what I want.

If I make queries against outlook.office365.com, I've got a 401 error.

If I put my access token in [this token analyzer](http://jwt.calebb.net/), it seems healthy although the scope field only shows the permissions I set in the AzureAd portal for Windows Azure Active Directory, not Office 365 Exchange Online.

I am kind of lost, any help would be welcome...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a choice:

1. Call the separate service apis - Your problem is that you acquired a token to call AAD, and then tried to use that to call Outlook - you need to make a separate call to acquire a token for outlook.office365.com through ADAL or through the token endpoint directly. The token acquired for AAD Graph can ONLY be used against AAD Graph.  Similarly the token acquired for Outlook can ONLY be used against Outlook APIs.

Just to clarify - Azure AD OAuth can protect/secure multiple web APIs, including O365 APIs, Azure AD Graph, Azure Resource Management APIs, your own APIs and the new O365 unified API.  In the first access token request, you specify the first resource you want/need to call.  It doesn't have to be AAD Graph - i.e. it's not the default AFAIK.  Based on what is consented to, you have the ability to request additional access tokens using the (multi-resource) refresh token.  Vittorio's blog post which you link to in your comments does a great job explaining this.

2. Call the O365 unified API (which is in preview) and IS documented.  See below.  The beauty of the unified API is that you only need to acquire a token to call graph.microsoft.com and ALL the entities on that endpoint are available to you AND more.  It removes the siloed nature of #1, and the requirement to get and manage multiple access tokens to call these different API endpoints.  However #1 is currently GA, and the unified API is preview only at this time.

For more on #2 please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview and search for "unified" in the list of samples here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/starter-projects-and-code-samples

We are working on improving the unified API documentation.  If you are making pure REST calls, then I recommend starting out with the [API explorer](https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/) (and try things like https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/events and https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/messages to get your calendar events and mail messages), OR the [API sandbox](https://apisandbox.msdn.microsoft.com/) (which can show you JS code snippets, and allow you to test your own easily enough).  As you can see on the REST examples, to access mail and calendar features in the unified APIs, you should be able to swap the service roots from Outlook to the unified API ie - https://outlook.office365.com/v1.0 -> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta. On the JS sample - we will be adding more capabilities here and additional samples.

NOTE:  Personal contacts available in outlook.office365.com are not available in the unified API yet.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
For #1: where can I get a token for outlook365? I browsed, but I always end up on a page explaining me how to setup my app on the azureAd portal, from which I guess I can only get graph API tokens.
For #2: the only sample I found for javascript using Graph endpoint does not do anything with contacts nor calendar. I still cannot find anything in the unified API for the calendar, and as for the contacts, the doc (https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/office-365-unified-api-in-depth) is pretty elusive.
Thanks for your answer though, I'll keep searching.

Comment: Ok, so I was very confused, but here is a part of the answer for those who like me did not get completely the peculiarity of AzureAd OAuth: when OAuthing against the AzureAd endpoint (login.microsoftonline.com), one is given an access token and a refresh token. By default, the access token is to access the Graph endpoint. If you want a token for outlook.office365.com, you have to specify it in the very confusingly documented "resource" field. Other important point: the refresh token is a multi ressource refresh token! It allows you to get access token for any API that you use through AzureAd!

Comment: Read this: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/14/adal-windows-azure-ad-and-multi-resource-refresh-tokens/

Comment: Hi Dan, the update is super interesting! I'll go for the Outlook 365 API because the personal contacts access is crucial for my app. I tried the root swapping, but with so many adjustment variables I was playing with that I missed it. I get that the API Explorer is under development, right now it is useful if you now what to query, but it would complete (supplant?) the doc magically if there was a typeahead feature, or anything suggesting the options available. Thanks again!